# Why is my onboarding app rendering step 3 briefly instead of just step 1?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Node.js JavaScript web app that displays an onboarding sequence of 3 steps on a single html page. When the user clicks "Finish" on step 3, a new page is loaded into the browser which renders an h1 element saying "Please select your preferred subscription plan.". If the user clicks the back button of the browser, the previous onboarding page is rendered showing step 1 again but for less than second the browser shows step 3 again briefly, shifts left a little then disappears followed by step 1 rendered. My question is why am I seeing step 3 for a short time at all and left shifting when it shouldn't be rendered at all? I can't deploy it as a production app like this as it is poor UX. Any help to get rid of this "glitch" is hugely appreciated.

Here is my `onboarding.html` file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Easy Cover for Schools - Introduction Continued</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
    <div class="onboarding-container">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="#" class="skip-btn">Skip</a>
            <div class="dots">
                <div class="dot active"></div>
                <div class="dot"></div>
                <div class="dot"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="steps">
                <div class="step">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/0/200/300" alt="">
                    <h3>Step 1</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                        laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="step">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="">
                    <h3>Step 2</h3>
                    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
                        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
                        mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="step">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300" alt="">
                    <h3>Step 3</h3>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium,
                        totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                        dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/onboarding.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my `styles.ccs` CSS file;

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.app-title {
    color: blue;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    font-family:cursive;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 2.0rem;
    font-weight:800;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 16px 0;
}

#intro-container {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;;
}

.intro-container p {
    margin: -2% 5% 5% 5%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.intro-button {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    top: -12px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.bg-image {
    background-image: url("http://localhost:3000/images/classroom 5120 x 3413.jpg");
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.intro-container {
    width:600px;
    height:620px;
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    top:35%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-35%);
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.login-form {
    width:400px;
    height:445px;
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.signup-form {
    width:400px;
    height:655px;
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

.footer-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.onboarding-container img {
    height: 180px;
    margin: 32px 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.onboarding-container {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.onboarding-container.active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.onboarding-container .content {
    background-color: #fff;
    max-width: 450px;
    padding-top: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.onboarding-container .steps {
    display: flex;
    width: 300%;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.onboarding-container .step {
    width: 100%;
}

.onboarding-container h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 32px;
}

.onboarding-container p {
    line-height: 1.8;
    padding: 0 32px;
    text-align: left;
}

.onboarding-container .next-btn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 18px 32px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.onboarding-container .skip-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #636363;
}

.onboarding-container .dots {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 8px;
}

.onboarding-container .dot {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #dbdbdb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 400ms ease;
}

.onboarding-container .dot.active {
    background-color: #222;
}
```

Here is my `subscriptionplans.html` file;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Subscription Plans</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please select your preferred subscription plan.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `onboarding.js` Javascript file;

```
const onboardingContainer = document.querySelector(".onboarding-container");
const skipBtn = document.querySelector(".onboarding-container .skip-btn");
const steps = document.querySelectorAll(".onboarding-container .step");
const stepsContainer = document.querySelector(".onboarding-container .steps");
const nextBtn = document.querySelector(".next-btn");
const dots = document.querySelectorAll(".onboarding-container .dot");

let stepPosition = 0;

let currentStep = 0;

onboardingContainer.classList.add("active");

skipBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    currentStep += 2;

    if (currentStep > 2) {

        window.location = "subscriptionplans.html";

    } else {

        stepPosition += steps[0].offsetWidth * 2.0;
        stepsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${-stepPosition}px)`;
        if (currentStep == steps.length - 1) {
            nextBtn.innerHTML = "Finish";
            skipBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        dots.forEach((d) => {
            d.classList.remove("active");
        });

        dots[currentStep].classList.add("active");

    }
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    currentStep++;

    if (currentStep == steps.length) {
        
        currentStep = 0;
        stepPosition = 0;
        stepsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(0px)`
        nextBtn.innerHTML = "Next";
        skipBtn.style.visibility = "visible";

        dots.forEach((d) => {
            d.classList.remove("active");
        });

        dots[currentStep].classList.add("active");

        window.location.href = "subscriptionplans.html";

    } else {

        stepPosition += steps[0].offsetWidth;
        stepsContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${-stepPosition}px)`;
        if (currentStep == steps.length - 1) {
            nextBtn.innerHTML = "Finish";
            skipBtn.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        dots.forEach((d) => {
            d.classList.remove("active");
        });

        dots[currentStep].classList.add("active");
    }

});
```

I have also included a YouTube link of the screen recording to show the strange behaviour when I click on the back button.

[Strange behaviour of onboarding page](https://youtu.be/_7vZON-ID-k)

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". Currently the title describes almost all of the questions asked about [javascript] :).

Comment: I have now edited the title. Hopefully that is better.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your CSS styling it's hard to replicate. However, you can try ensuring the page is reloaded when accessing from history (using the back button), by adding this code to the **top** of your **JS file**:

```js
const perfEntries = performance.getEntriesByType("navigation");

if (perfEntries[0].type === "back_forward") {
    location.reload();
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks Tyrell. I have added the Javascript code but it didn't help.

Comment: CSS file added now.

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity thanks, I tried with the CSS added and can't seem to replicate the issue you are experiencing. Have you tried using a different browser for testing to see if it persists? I would also suggest clearing your browser's cache and trying again - or, trying in incognito mode.